# Istio - multiple routing rules performance?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a system deployed on Kubernetes and having traffic managed by Istio.

In my system I have to dynamically declare **many** SNI routing rules (estimation of 10,000 rules). These rules are constantly changing (e.g. routes added / removed all the time, dynamically).

As I understand, I have 2 options:

- Declare single VirtualService with 10,000 rules inside
- Declare 10,000 VirtualServices each one with single rule

Is there a difference between two approaches (performance wise / management wise)? Is there a practical limit of number of Services / Rules which can be defined?